# Opening serial port with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, serial-port

I am having problems with opening serial port in Qt. The error message I receive after failed attempt to open the port is `UnsupportedOperationError`. I would like to point out couple things:

- The port I am trying to open is implemented in an ARM MCU using USB (CDC),
- I can open the port in other application (like teraterm or realterm),
- I was able to open the port in my Qt application just a minute a go. I added some code in the ARM device (not concerning the USB functionality at all) and I couldnt open the port in Qt anymore.
- I tested that I can send/ receive the data on the port opened in other program (ie. realterm),
- The port works in other applications, but not Qt (tried the terminal example from Qt creator and it cannot open the port as well),

I have come across this behaviour in the past, but did not have time to go further into it. Now it is blocking me. What could be the case here with opening the port? Does qt put any additional requirements to it? I would really appreciate all help.
I am running qt on windows machine.

Edit: This is a part of the Terminal example from Qt creator responsible for opening the port.

```
void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{
    SettingsDialog::Settings p = settings->settings();
    serial->setPortName(p.name);
    serial->setBaudRate(p.baudRate);
    serial->setDataBits(p.dataBits);
    serial->setParity(p.parity);
    serial->setStopBits(p.stopBits);
    serial->setFlowControl(p.flowControl);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        console->setEnabled(true);
        console->setLocalEchoEnabled(p.localEchoEnabled);
        ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(false);
        ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(true);
        ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(false);
        showStatusMessage(tr("Connected to %1 : %2, %3, %4, %5, %6")
                          .arg(p.name).arg(p.stringBaudRate).arg(p.stringDataBits)
                          .arg(p.stringParity).arg(p.stringStopBits).arg(p.stringFlowControl));
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open serial port " << serial->portName() << "Error: " << serial->error();
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), serial->errorString());

        showStatusMessage(tr("Open error"));
    }
}
```

I have added the line qith `qDebug` in order to show the error message. Its is the same as in my Qt program.

Comment: without knowing the changes and your code it would be hard do do a troubleshooting here. did you create a minimal Qt example for testing ?

Comment: The "Terminal" example is quite minimal from the Qt creator. Also this is regarding my code in ARM, not Qt. The point is I can open the port with other programs, but not Qt. I have looked into the qserialport.cpp file to look for `UnsupportedOperationError` string. The problem is I cannot find any matching error code. My error string is `QSerialPort::SerialPortError(UnsupportedOperationError)`.

Comment: does the "Terminal" example from the Qt creator is showing the same error ? Please provide a minimal version of the program for traceability

Comment: Yes the Terminal example gives the exact same error. I will add mwe.

Comment: can you post the error code too ? UnsupportedOperationError ist only the error message. the reason code (error code: serial->error()) may lead to the exact problem.

Comment: But I have a .dll file, not the .cpp file. I have found the source online.

Comment: The error message is the error code (its an enum). The method only returns true or false.

Comment: well regarding you example code:qDebug() << "Failed to open serial port " << serial->portName() << "Error: " << serial->error(); <-- it should give the error number too ! And serial->errorString() should provide the string "UnsupportedOperationError"

Comment: In that case the error code is 10 (enum value for QSerialPort::UnsupportedOperationError).

Comment: I tried to re-create your problem and used the following example code I wrote: see sserial.h https://paste.ubuntu.com/24783851/  
But everything I tried worked as expected and I am unable to get this Error "UnsupportedOperationError".Without details about "I added some code in the ARM device" it is hard to determinate the problem. Please run this minimalistic program and let me know if this is working or not.

Comment: Thanks for help. It would be rather hard to recreate 1:1 because its a custom board with freeRTOS software running there... Its an STM32F407VTG6 based device. The code for the CDC peripheral was generated using cubeMX. I know it cant help much, but you wont be able to run it anyways without the target board. I wonder what are the other options to get this error in the qt app. Please note that I still can open the port in other programs running without qt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145891/discussion-between-lkj-and-bremen).

Answer (score 1):

You're facing a bug or an overly exclusionary behavior in Qt. There is unlikely to be anything you can do to fix it in your own code.

It's also impossible to debug without a debug build of Qt. Use a debug build and you can pin-point exactly where in the implementation of `QSerialPort` it fails. You'll then know what's going on, and be able to file a Qt bug report based on that. Since you'll be set up to build Qt, you can fix the bug yourself and get going quickly that way.